# Install python-psycopg on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, python

How can I install python-psycopg (not python-psycopg2) on Ubuntu 9.10

"apt-get install python-psycopg" returns "Package python-psycopg has no installation candidate"

I also downloaded source code at [psycopg-1.1.21.tar.gz](http://initd.org/pub/software/psycopg/psycopg-1.1.21.tar.gz) but "make" command was no found in the archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*python-psycopg* is only available in Ubuntu until 9.04.

If the *make* command is not found you have to install the package *make*. Make sure you have installed anything else mentioned in the "*Compile-time configuration options*" section of the *README* file.

Answer (score 0):

> "make" command was no found in the archive

Did you try python setup.py install?

Comment: The archive has no `setup.py`, but it does have a `Makefile`.